# Are the Japanese names of the characters from Ente Isla references to something?

Tags: the-devil-is-a-part-timer

I feel like there is some kind of joke with the characters' fake names that I am missing.

One of the characters I think asks if their names are outdated. Is that the joke, just that they are using archaic names? Or is there something else?

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking what "the joke" is with names like "Maou Sadao" and "Yusa Emi", the joke is that their Japanese names sound suspiciously similar to their Ente Isla names/titles:

- "Maou Sadao" is very close to "Maou Satan" / "Demon Lord Satan"
- "Yusa Emi" is very close to "Yuusha Emi" / "Hero Emi"
- "Ashiya (Shirou)" is sort of close to "Alciel" (*Arushieru*)
- "Urushihara (Hanzou)" is sort of close to "Lucifer" (*Rushiferu*)

As a side effect of this, some of their Japanese names sound curious/archaic, since you kind of have to stretch to find Japanese names that sound similar to Christian angel/devil names.

Separately, some of the names are also "translation jokes", so to speak:

- The "Suzu" (鈴) in "Kamazuki Suzuno" means "bell". Indeed, her Ente Isla name is "Crestia Bell".

Comment: I got the feeling that Maou Sadao's name is also a reference to Madao (maru de dame na ossan i.e. a good for nothing) from Gintama.

Comment: @Ayase Eri There's no relation whatsoever. Sadao is a legit Japanese name, whereas Madao is not. Also, their personalities bear no resemblance (I'd hardly call Maou a "good-for-nothing"), so I'm not sure why you saw this to be a reference, outside that it's a one-letter difference.

Comment: He is a good employee, but a good for nothing when it comes to being a Maou.

Comment: @AyaseEri Not really. He is actually really good at being "overlord" as he drove humans into corner only to be defeated by Emilia.